# Issue running Active Directory Rights Management Services administration after installation

Tags: active-directory

I'm unable to run the Active Directory Rights Management Services administration console after adding the role to a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

Before adding the role, I created a new website in IIS called **WRMS**. I set the site to use SSL, assigned our certificate to it, and added a host name **wrms.ourdomain.com** to the site bindings.  During the Add Role process, I pointed the wizard to this site when asked where to host the WRMS administration site.

The role installed successfully, however, when I attempt to open the Active Directory Rights Management Services administration console, I get the following error popup:

> The connecting with local AD RMS administration service failed because the value of "AdminLocalConnectionPoint" under registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\DRMS\2.0" was invalid.

The value of that registry key is **https://wrms.ourdomain.com**.  I don't see anything relevant in the application logs.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The RMS blog has a post about [issues/workarounds when installing SSL with RMS](http://blogs.msdn.com/rms/archive/2006/08/04/enabling-ssl-after-rms-is-provisioned.aspx) (note this is for RMS for Windows Server 2003):

> Whew! Now for the fun stuff. To enable SSL in your RMS environment after the RMS server has been provisioned, you should follow these steps:
>
> - Provision a new RMS server using the HTTPS option for the Intranet Cluster URL.
> - Configure the old server as a Trusted User Domain on the new server. For instruction on this, see http://technet2.microsoft.com/WindowsServer/f/?en/Library/1c96ee74-fd28-4511-be21-087e2b04c3ee1033.mspx
> - Configure the old server as a Trusted Publishing Domain on the new server. For more information on this, see http://technet2.microsoft.com/WindowsServer/f/?en/Library/1c96ee74-fd28-4511-be21-087e2b04c3ee1033.mspx
> - Add a new String Value named LicenseServerRedirection registry entry to all of your RMS clients. The registry entry should be added to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\DRM. The value of this entry should be set to the name of the new server in the format of https://NewRMSServer/_wmcs/licensing.
> - Update your Active Directory Service Connection Point to the new server. This can be done manually or via the ADScpRegister utility available from the RMS Toolkit. NOTE: You must be a member of the  Active Directory Enterprise Admins group to do this.
> - Retire the old RMS server.

You may need to use the ADScpRegister utility from (included wtih RMS for Windows Server 2008, located in "C:\Program Files\RMS SP2 Administration Toolkit" ) to re-register the the URL:
`ADScpRegister unregisterscp`

Here is a [guide for installing RMS on Windows Server 2008](http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2008/06/26/windows-2008-rights-management-services-install.aspx), that discusses the ADScpRegister utility.

Comment: I don't have an explicit requirement for the WRMS administration site to use SSL.  Didn't think it would cause me such frustration :) 

I'm going to remove the role and reconfigure it so the WRMS site doesn't use SSL.

Thanks for your help, shufler